# How to change color for LayerSwitcher?

Tags: css, openlayers

I tried to change the layerswitcher color. But its not changed. Here is my code.
I tried in javascript also  osMap.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({ 'activeColor': "white", 'fontColor': "black" })); but there is no effect.

```
.olControlLayerSwitcher
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        right: 0;
        width: 20em;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        font-size: smaller;
        color: white;
        background-color: transparent;
        z-index: 10000;
    }
    .olControlLayerSwitcher .layersDiv
    {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OL CSS is set within a `style` attribute and is stronger than your override.
You must use `!important` to override it:

```
background-color: #CCCCCC !important;
```

See [CSS specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Comment: Yes..anyother alternative?

Comment: Wait for OpenLayers 3 :) maybe, I am sure it will be easier with that version.